# Openshift : Failing to push and pull images to local Image repository (172.30.1.1:5000) : NO_PROXY/noProxy/no-proxy not honoured

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, docker-registry, docker-for-mac, okd

Can anyone throw some light to resolve making NO_PROXY work for local image registry on MAC? - Tried all options/workaround that have come across various forums/threads, but none seems to work.

**Issue:**

**Pushing**
Pushing image 172.30.1.1:5000/oc-prj001/s2i-spring-boot-app-thin:latest ..
Registry server Address: 
Registry server User Name: serviceaccount
Registry server Email: serviceaccount@example.org
Registry server Password: <>
error: build error: Failed to push image: Get http://172.30.1.1:5000/v2/:  net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

**Pulling**
Failed to pull image "172.30.1.1:5000/oc-prj001/s2i-spring-boot-app-thin": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get http://172.30.1.1:5000/v2/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

**oc cluster up :**. [warnings of possible issue]

WARNING: An HTTP proxy (gateway.docker.internal:3128) is configured for the Docker daemon, but you did not specify one for cluster up
WARNING: An HTTPS proxy (gateway.docker.internal:3129) is configured for the Docker daemon, but you did not specify one for cluster up
WARNING: A proxy is configured for Docker, however 172.30.1.1 is not included in its NO_PROXY list.
   172.30.1.1 needs to be included in the Docker daemon's NO_PROXY environment variable so pushes to the local OpenShift registry can succeed

**Desktop : macOS Catalina (10.15.4)
Docker Desktop for MAC: 2.2.0.5
Openshift origin : 3.11**

Comment: Are you running openshift on your mac or minishift?

Comment: okd on docker desktop., now switched to minishift and able to make things work on mac.  There seems like issue with new version of docker desktop or OC (?) taking the NO_PROXY settings.